# Best practices for hiding/showing HTML elements based on current subscriber's subscription?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just looking for best practice suggestions on hiding/showing HTML elements based on a user's subscription status.  I'm aware of client side Javascript to do the job, but I'm not sure if that would be a best practice.

In a nutshell, I'm developing a Heroku app that is based off of Node.js and has a plain HTML front end.  This Heroku app will eventually be able to be purchased/used at a subscription/tier level.  So, if a user subscribes to the "Tier 1" package, for example, I want to be able to hide certain elements from the HTML form that they aren't "paying" for.  I know I can do this via Javascript, but is there a better, more secure way to accomplish hiding/showing certain elements?

Example: here's a snippet of what I would want to hide:

```
<div id="actionSection">
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="stacked-input-id-01">Action Button 1</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <input type="text" id="action1" placeholder="Action Name" class="slds-input" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="stacked-input-id-01">Action Button 2</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <input type="text" id="action2" placeholder="Action Name" class="slds-input" />
                        </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, I can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("actionSection").style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

But is there a better way to do this that is more secure and scalable?

Comment: well of course it is not a better way to hide them on the client side.. you should use server side rendering to render only content meant to be for a user. If I was one of your user I could proxy the request and remove all the js code preventing me to use all benifits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be secure, you need to check the subscription status in the backend. A seasoned developer can manipulate anything in the frontend.

I'm not sure, but Heroku has probably a solution that works out of the box similar [Netlify Identity](https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/identity/)

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` to the sections you want to hide. Create a constant array and put those `ids` in that array. Create a new function and call that function on selection of tier. Inside the function iterate that array and add a `hide` class to those elements

```
const arr = ['id1','id2','id3'];
function hideElem(arr){
  if(arr.length === 0){
   return;
 }
 arr.forEach((item)=>{
  document.getElementById(item).classList.add('hide')
  })
}

function onTierSelect(){
  hideElem(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say do something on the node.js side that checks their session variable (I assume you made them login at some point, and thus, server keeps session variables for them) and displays the appropriate sections. As they can't change session variable on the server (it's all set by you and not accessible to them) it should be "reasonably" secure.

Then your node.js app would only serve up the portion the user is authorized for by checking the variable each time.